# Deleting dynamically created inputs

Tags: javascript

So is there an easy way to get the last node so I could simply delete inputs from the last one? deleteinput() function.

```
<script>

    var form = document.getElementById("form");


    function newinput(){    
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        form.appendChild(input);
    }
    function deleteinput(){

        form.removeChild();

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add your `input`s some `id` as well so you can delete them by providing `id` as an argument to your `deleteinput()` function.

Your function will look like this

```
function deleteinput(name) {
    var input = document.getElementByName(name);
    form.removeChild(input);
}
```

Also `newinput()` will change accordingly:

```
function newinput(name) {
    var input = document.createEleement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    input.name = name;
    form.appendChild(input);
}
```

You can also create some global integer and generate name of input automatically by some string + incremented value of your global variable - this way you don't need to pass `name` argument to `newinput()` function.

I am not sure that this will 100% work, I did not test it. Maybe you will need to tweak it little bit but the main logic should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lastChild` property to get the last child, and the `previousSibling` to step through them until you get to an `input`

```
function deleteinput() {
    for (var child = form.lastChild; child.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'input'; child = child.previousSibling) {
    }
    if (child) {
        form.deleteChild(child);
    }
}
```

Comment: any way to make it only delete inputs not everything that is a child in that form?

Comment: I added a loop to go through the children in reverse order until it gets to an input

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get and remove the last element this way.

```
var ele = document.getElementById("parent element Id").lastChild;
ele.remove();
```